# Elasticsearch server starts with following exception

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and AWS ec2 and my elasticsearch server (deployed over AWS EC2 instance) is starting with following exception:

```
[2015-01-23 06:36:44,919][ERROR][marvel.agent] [elasticnode] exporter [es_exporter] has thrown an exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.Utils.extractHostsFromHttpServer(Utils.java:90)
        at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ESExporter.openAndValidateConnection(ESExporter.java:344)
        at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ESExporter.openExportingConnection(ESExporter.java:212)
        at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ESExporter.exportXContent(ESExporter.java:275)
        at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ESExporter.exportNodeStats(ESExporter.java:173)
        at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.AgentService$ExportingWorker.exportNodeStats(AgentService.java:305)
        at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.AgentService$ExportingWorker.run(AgentService.java:225)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am not able to figure out the exact reason for this. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marvel tries to connect to elasticsearch before it is fully initialized.  You can safely ignore that error unless it persists.